# Foreman/puppet : cant able to see the nodes or agents in "ALL HOSTS"

Tags: linux, centos, puppet, theforeman

I have configured foreman master and foreman node. I can able to see the signed certificates in "smart proxies tab" but not in "ALL HOSTS" i cannot able to monitor my clients(All i can able to see is foreman-master and their reports)

puppet agent --test is successful. please help me with this.

Comment: How did you set up it?  Was it an existing Puppet master?  If pre-existing, did you set up reporting, an ENC or fact uploads?

Comment: No,it is not an existing puppetmaster, i have followed this documentation 
Foreman master setup - http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-foreman-with-puppet-in-centos-and-ubuntu/ 
Adding node to foreman - http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-add-puppet-nodes-to-foreman/

Comment: Have you configured your puppetmaster to send reports or anything to Foreman?  Those guides don't appear to deal with that, only a standalone Foreman instance (though I'd *strongly* recommend that unless you're really very familiar with how this all works).  http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.9/index.html#3.5.4PuppetReports details setting this up.